# Почему функция срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: c#

Есть две формы MainForm и HackedForm.
Когда я нажимаю на главной форме "дешифровать" происходит следующее:

```
        try
        {
            SCurrentData.Text = textBox.Text;
            HackModeForm hmf = new HackModeForm();
            SCurrentData.openHackedForm = true;
            hmf.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Открывается форма Hacked. При открытии формы Hacked:

```
InitializeComponent();
Text = "Дешифрование!";
textBox1.Text = SCurrentData.Text;
tables = new Stack<Dictionary<char, char>>();
```

Статический класс SCurrentData:

```
    public static string Text;
    public static Dictionary<char, char> Table = new Dictionary<char, char>();

    public static string HFText;
    public static Dictionary<char, char> HFTable = new Dictionary<char, char>();

    public static bool openHackedForm = false;
```

openHackedForm - показывает, когда открыта HackedForm.
Проблема в следующем: 
Текст из textBox HackedForm, когда она открыта должен копироваться через статический класс(поле HFText) в textBox MainForm. Когда я открываю форму первый раз так и происходит, но вот второй и более уже нет.

Код таймера MainForm:

```
        if (SCurrentData.openHackedForm)
        {
            textBox.Text = SCurrentData.HFText;

            Dictionary<char, char> dict = new Dictionary<char, char>();
            dict = SCurrentData.HFTable;

            dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (var item in dict)
            {
                object[] p = new object[2];
                p[0] = item.Key;
                p[1] = item.Value;
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                row.CreateCells(dataGridView, p);
                dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            tables.Push(TakeDict());
        }
```

Код таймера HAckedForm:

```
        SCurrentData.HFText = textBox1.Text;
        if (Duplicate() == false && dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            SCurrentData.HFTable = TakeDict();
        }
```

Код При закрытии(событие формы)

```
    private void HackModeForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        SCurrentData.HFText = textBox1.Text;
        SCurrentData.openHackedForm = false;
    }
```

Comment: «Когда я открываю форму первый раз так и происходит, но вот второй и более уже нет.» — откуда вы это знаете? Вы смотрели в отладчике?

Comment: И где у вас сбрасывается `SCurrentData.openHackedForm`?

Comment: @VladD я смотрел когда пользовался программой. Жму кнопку все норм, второй раз жму - не норм.

Comment: @VladD поправил, добавил код при закрытии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в данном коде крылась в таймере(HackedModeForm). Он не останавливался. Чтобы его остановить нужно прописать при закрытии `timer1.Enabled = false;` Тогда всё будет работать.